# How can I switch from one page to another using an AppBars TabBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a simple custom AppBar with the following code (I've taken out some code for simplification. It's not necessary for the question.):

```
class SimpleAppBarPageState extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorWeight: 5,
          tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text('1',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            ),
            Tab(child: Text('2',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        elevation: 20,
        titleSpacing: 20,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          buildPageOne(),
          buildPageTwo()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Now I have two dart files of which one contains the code for Page one and the other file contains the code for page two.

Now I want page one to be open when Tab '1' is selected and page two should be open when Tab '2' is selected.

Therefor I thought of defining a new Widget which opens the corresponding page. Here are my thoughts:

```
Widget buildPageOne() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PageOne()
      ),
    );
  }
```

I think this last code sample is complete useless, but it kind of shows my intention what should happen.

Can you guys help me out to solve this problem?

I'd be very happy about an answer!
Greetings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter, navigate to new Widget while maintaining AppBar and Bottom TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937065/in-flutter-navigate-to-new-widget-while-maintaining-appbar-and-bottom-tabbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use Navigator if you are using Tabs.
Second you need a **TabController** to handle your Tabs e.g. you can use the [DefaultTabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController-class.html). With [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) you can set the text/icon of each tab below the Appbar. Within your [TabBarView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) you set your Widgets you want to display. In your case omit the Navigator and just provide the Widgets you want to display in **TabBarView**

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: 'Tabs',
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs:[
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        Widget1(),
        Widget2()
      ]
      ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use methods to navigator to new screen.
Create 2 separate stateless or statefull widgets: Widget1(), Widget2(),

And in childrens of TabBarView use these 2 widgets as children.

```
body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        Widget1(),
        Widget2(),
      ],
    ),
```

Save them, do a hot restart

Comment: I think this answer leads in the right direction. Yet I do not understand what to do. Can you add a little more detail?

Comment: Just remove the buildPageOne and buildPageTwo methods from the childrens of tabbarview, replace them with PageOne() and PageTwo().....   Provided PageOne() and PageTwo() be a stateless or stateful widget